# connecting html to css file tree

Tags: css, ejs

I'm having a problem connecting my ejs file to my css file. I know that this is basic, but I've tried several ways including:

/css/dev.css, ./css/dev.css, /dev.css, ../dev.css, ../css/dev.css.

I've also tried adding the following code to my app.js file:

app.use(express.static('public'));

I know that the css is good because when I copy it and paste it inline into the ejs file as a style tag, everything works. I don't want to do this however because it's generally bad practice. I'm probably missing something obvious here.

[connecting home.ejs to dev.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oteQc.png)

Comment: try `./css/dev.css`

Comment: Or maybe css/dev.css

Comment: Thanks guys but neither work

Comment: you need to refer that from the place where the html will be loaded (meaning something like a build directory which is exposed to the port). What server are you using?

Comment: I'm using cloud9 IDE so I'm running locally and using their server

Comment: Solved: I had to install express serve-static, require it, and access it in the ejs file with:                    href="stylesheets/dev.css"              
                                                                                                   
var serveStatic = require('serve-static'); 
app.use(express.static('public/'));